# Solr sometimes fails to parse the query as if it haven't fully received it

Tags: solr

I'm running some tests with Solr. I run a script to build a query from a test cases and then send with `curl` to my local Solr instance. Sometimes the queries run fine, but sometimes **the same query** fails to with `Unexpected EOF` error. The same means exactly same, I just repeat the command and instead of an empty list it shows the expected result. When I look at the response XML I get with errors I indeed see a truncated JSON there. The JSON file on disk is, of course, complete. Small queries run fine, the problem starts to appear with longer queries, which seem to fail more often than succeed. The queries I'm trying to test are rather long and complex.

What might be the problem?

It's Solr 8.2.0, local instance on a rather underpowered Mac Mini with OS X 10.11.6. My found set is tiny, I'm trying to figure out the logic of complex joins.

I also remember seeing similar errors even when I tried relatively simple queries with Solr dashboard (i.e. `http://<host>:8983/solr/#/<collection>/query`), except that I got them rather consistently (or it just didn't occur to me to try re-sending them) and interpreted them as a problem with my query syntax.

**Update**: the query that fails is 2829 bytes, the `EOF` happens around character 1400 or so, always the same place. I'm sending it with `curl` as JSON query to the `select` handle; the collection is based on the `default` configuration with a few custom field types and fields, the `solrconfig.xml` is not changed.

**Update 2**: got the log entry, it's same, except there's a stack trace. What seems to be interesting is that the JSON is always truncated to the same size: the `position` of error is always `1460`.

```
2020-02-24 10:19:05.103 ERROR (qtp1357563986-23) [   x:proof]
o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: 
Unexpected EOF: char=(EOF),position=1460 AFTER='<redacted>'
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:452)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.getMore(JSONParser.java:248)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.readStringChars2(JSONParser.java:754)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.readStringChars(JSONParser.java:734)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.getStringChars(JSONParser.java:1206)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.getString(JSONParser.java:1193)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getString(ObjectBuilder.java:79)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getVal(ObjectBuilder.java:51)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getObject(ObjectBuilder.java:140)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getVal(ObjectBuilder.java:63)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getObject(ObjectBuilder.java:140)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getVal(ObjectBuilder.java:63)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getVal(ObjectBuilder.java:36)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.fromJSON(ObjectBuilder.java:32)
    at org.apache.solr.request.json.RequestUtil.mergeJSON(RequestUtil.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.request.json.RequestUtil.processParams(RequestUtil.java:180)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrPluginUtils.setDefaults(SolrPluginUtils.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:196)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2578)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:780)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:566)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:423)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How long are these queries? How are you sending them? Do you get a stack trace on the Solr side with a more extended error?

Comment: @MatsLindh, the query that fails is 2829 bytes, the `EOF` happens around character 1400 or so, always the same place. I'm sending it with `curl` as JSON query to the `select` handle; the collection is based on the default configuration with a few custom field types and fileds, the `solrconfig.xml` is not changed. Will check the log file separately.

Comment: @MatsLindh Added the log entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: the `curl` request was sent without `content-type`; once I've set it to `application/json`, things started to work.